# Do CNAME mapping of my subdomain to Sendgrid for link branding using Amazon Cloudfront CDN

Tags: amazon-web-services, cname-record, amazon-cloudfront, cdn, sendgrid

I want to have link branding with SSL on my `domain example.com`, so I created sub-domain `abc.example.com`, I want this `abc.example.com` to CNAME to `sendgrid.net`.

I have done CNAME mapping but it seems `abc.example.com` is CNAME for `d3534534.cloudfront.net`, How to do the needful? Sendgrid provides doc for some other CDNs like Cloudflare, KeyCDN & Fastly, mentioned [here](https://sendgrid.com/docs/ui/sending-email/content-delivery-networks/), but I am facing issue with AWS CloudFront and unable to found any specific doc for this.

Screenshot for the error at Sendgrid is as below:

[image: Error On Sendgrid]

Comment: This is a DNS record and you must set it in your DNS zone.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, In DNS I can set CNAME but SSL can't be added there, I need to [set up SSL for click tracking in Sendgrid](https://sendgrid.com/docs/ui/analytics-and-reporting/click-tracking-ssl/) using CDN.

Comment: OK, but you asked a question about DNS.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, Thanks for trying to help, but my question is actually a combination of DNS, Cloudfront CDN and Sendgrid Link Branding, hence added the appropriate tags.